# vba excel 2007 referencing data?

Tags: vba, charts, excel-2007

I am inheriting some VBA code from other people. the.......some other code is to make chart of some existing data in excel. I just dont get where the source datasets are referenced. what is the data for x-axis? what is the data from y-axis??..........

........some other code............

'**********************************
'*********CHARTS*******************
'***********************************

```
    Windows(nm_driver).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A19") = ""
    'intialize the cell as empty

    '*******Copies the previous sheet and makes a new sheet********
    Windows(nm_out).Activate
    Sheets(2).Select
    Sheets(2).Copy After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
    j = j + 1
    Sheets(j).Select
    Debug.Print "j=" & j
    Windows(nm_driver).Activate
    out_sht_nm = ActiveSheet.Range("A8") & " Plots"
    Debug.Print "out_sht_nm" & out_sht_nm

    ActiveSheet.Range("A10").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(nm_out).Activate
    Sheets(j).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("H1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False '****Paste the heading in the plots tab*****
    Sheets(j).Name = out_sht_nm     '**** Assign the Sheet's name******
    Debug.Print "out_sht_nm=" & out_sht_nm

    '*********copies the actual data for seq num*********

    Windows(nm_inp2).Activate

    Sheets(i).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("B3:B23").Select
    'i could use usedrange here
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(nm_out).Activate
    Sheets(j).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


    Windows(nm_inp2).Activate
    Sheets(i).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Select
    col_len = Selection.End(xlToRight).Column
    Debug.Print "col_len=" & col_len


    p = 3

    '*******This FOR loop if for checking till where we have columns ending with *_XB
    For x = col_len To 1 Step -1
        Debug.Print "x=" & x
        Windows(nm_inp2).Activate

        Sheets(i).Select
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, x).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows(nm_driver).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("A24").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        If ActiveSheet.Range("A25") = "_Xb" Then
            Start = x
        Debug.Print "start=" & Start
        End If

    Next x


    '*******This FOR loop is to copy all the remaining columns from the input file*********
    For k = 3 To Start - 1
    'these columns do not end with _xb
        Debug.Print "k=" & k
        Windows(nm_inp2).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, k).Select

        Selection.Copy
        Windows(nm_driver).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("A19").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        flag = ActiveSheet.Range("A21").Text        '***It just checks if the column does not end with _SL_?

        If flag = "_SL_" Then
        'do nothing

        Else

            Windows(nm_inp2).Activate
            Sheets(i).Select
            ActiveSheet.Cells(3, k).Select

            ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            Selection.Copy

            Windows(nm_out).Activate
            ActiveSheet.Cells(3, p).Select

            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            p = p + 1       '*******Variable (p) is still incrementing as we need to append the remaing columns after the *_XB columns********
        End If

        Debug.Print "flag=" & flag


    Next k

    '****This FOR loop is for pasting the columns which are ending with *_XB and creating the charts*****
    For k = Start To col_len

        Windows(nm_inp2).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, k).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows(nm_driver).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("A19").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        flag = ActiveSheet.Range("A21").Text    '***It just checks if the column does not end with _SL_?

        If flag = "_SL_" Then


        Else

            chart_title = ActiveSheet.Range("A14").Text

            '**Copies the column which ends with *_XB from the spline consist input file***
            '***Variable (k) is for iterating the columns in the spline consist input file******
            Windows(nm_inp2).Activate
            Sheets(i).Select
            ActiveSheet.Cells(3, k).Select
            ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            Selection.Copy

            '*****Pastes it in the output file and then creates the chart*******
            'Variable (p) is for iterating the columns in the output file******
            Windows(nm_out).Activate
            ActiveSheet.Cells(3, p).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


            p = p + 1

        End If

    Next k
    Debug.Print "k=" & k
    Debug.Print "p=" & p
    Debug.Print "chart_title=" & chart_title

    '*********** Creating charts and labelling the X-Axis accordingly****************

    start_2 = ((p - 3) / 2) + 3
    Z = 105
    m = 0
    n = 0

    Debug.Print "start_2=" & start_2
    For b = 3 To start_2 - 1

        Windows(nm_out).Activate
        Sheets(j).Select
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, b).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows(nm_driver).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("A19").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        chart_title = ActiveSheet.Range("A14").Text

        Windows(nm_out).Activate
        Sheets(j).Select
        text1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, b).Text

        alp_in = 0

        For c = start_2 To p - 1
            text2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, c).Text
            If UCase(Left(text2, Len(text2) - 3)) = UCase(text1) Then
                alp_in = c
            End If
        Next c

        Debug.Print "alp_in=" & alp_in

        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, b).Select
        ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Z).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, alp_in).Select
        ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Z + 1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Z) = ""
        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Z + 1) = chart_title

        ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Z + 1).Select
        row_end = Selection.End(xlDown).Row
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, Z), Cells(row_end, Z + 1)).Select

        Debug.Print "row_end=" & row_end

        Call border_design

        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
        ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
        ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "MyChart" & Z
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
        Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelSpacing = 2

        With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("MyChart" & Z)
            .Height = 260 ' resize
            .Width = 290  ' resize
            .Left = m * 300
            .Top = n * 270 + 600

        End With

        '**** Variable (m) defines the left alignment of the chart and Variable (n) defines teh top alignment of the chart***
        '**These variables are used because the requirement was to have only 3 charts in a row****

        ActiveChart.Legend.Select
        Selection.Delete
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
        ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleVertical)
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Log Odds"
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = -100
        'ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = chart_title
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Font.Size = 10
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True


        m = m + 1
        If m = 3 Then
           m = 0
           n = n + 1
        End If
        Z = Z + 2
    'm and n is to control the position of the chart
    Next b



    '********Now we have to create the Charts for the class variables as well which are coming from raw_data
    'input file****
    Windows(nm_driver).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("AA1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)) = ""
    ActiveSheet.Range("AB1") = ""

    '*****Copies all the spline variables that are in the output file into the driver******
    '***Basically this will check if the variable coming from raw_data input file is a part of the spline variable or not***
    Windows(nm_out).Activate
    Sheets(j).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(nm_driver).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("AA1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    'transpose=true here converts row into column

    Windows(nm_inp1).Activate
    Sheets(i).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Select
    tot_row = Selection.End(xlDown).Row '****Gives the total number of rows in raw_data input file*****

    v = 53          '******Variable (v) defines the column number where the class variables will get pasted in the M18 plots sheet****


    '****This FOR loop checks every variable of raw_data input file (only column A) with the list of spline variables and see if
    'it is a spline variable or a class variable. if it comes out to be a spline variable it leaves it and if it comes out to
    'be class variable it copies it in the M18 plots sheet and creates a graph out of that*********


    For g = 3 To tot_row

        Windows(nm_inp1).Activate
        text1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(g, 1).Text

        end1 = g

        Windows(nm_driver).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("AB1") = text1
        sum1 = ActiveSheet.Range("AC26")
        If sum1 = 1 Then
        '*****Checking if the variable is spline or class; if spline then sum1 = 1 else sum1 =0 ***

        Else
            Windows(nm_inp1).Activate

            '*****This FOR loop checks for the number of rows that single variable has in the raw_data input file*****
            For h = g + 1 To tot_row
                text11 = ActiveSheet.Cells(h, 1).Text
                If text11 = text1 Then
                    end1 = h        '****end1 variable gives the row number that has the last occurance of the variable from the raw_data input file*****
                End If
            Next h

            heading1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(g, 1).Text
            '****The variable name***
            Windows(nm_driver).Activate
            ActiveSheet.Range("A19") = heading1

            chart_title = ActiveSheet.Range("A14").Text     '****Chart title is a combination of sheet name and variable name***

            Windows(nm_out).Activate
            Sheets(j).Select
            ActiveSheet.Cells(3, v + 1) = chart_title   '****Pastes the chart_title in the M18 plots sheet
            ActiveSheet.Cells(3, v) = "bin"             '****Pastes the text "bin" in the M18 plots sheet



            Windows(nm_inp1).Activate
            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(g, 3), Cells(end1, 4)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Windows(nm_out).Activate
            Sheets(j).Select
            ActiveSheet.Cells(4, v).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            '****Selects the full table and gives the border****
            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, v), Cells(3, v + 1)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            With Selection
                    .WrapText = False
            'Call border_design
            End With
```

'****************************************************************
'****************************************************************
'*********************create chart******************************
'**************************************************************
'***************************************************************
                ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
                ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
                ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "MyChart" & v
                ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
                Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
                ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelSpacingIsAuto = True

```
            'use parent property here
            With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("MyChart" & v)
                .Height = 260 ' resize
                .Width = 290  ' resize
                .Left = m * 300
                .Top = n * 270 + 600

            End With

            ActiveChart.Legend.Select
            Selection.Delete
            ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
            ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleVertical)
            ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Log Odds"
            ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
            ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = -100
            ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = chart_title
            ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Font.Size = 10
            ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True

            m = m + 1
            If m = 3 Then
               m = 0
               n = n + 1
            End If
            v = v + 2
            g = end1

         End If

    Next g

    Windows(nm_out).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select
    Call border_design
    ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True

    ActiveSheet.Range("BA3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

Next i



Windows(nm_out).Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets(1).Delete
Sheets(1).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Sheets(1).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Windows(nm_inp1).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Windows(nm_inp2).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Windows(nm_driver).Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

MsgBox "Completed"

ans2 = MsgBox("Do you want to OPEN the Output File just created ??", vbYesNo)

If ans2 = vbYes Then
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=mv_file_sv_nm
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: The code section you posted doesn't contain the range. Can you post more of the code before the snippet above?

Comment: I should clarify why we need the extra code. Excel is likely using the active cell to create the chart, and because Excel is smart (sometimes!) it can infer a range structured as a table simply using one cell. So we're looking for what the active cell is. Another idea would be to look at the chart settings after the VBA creates it, and find where the source is. That may give you a clue when looking in the code.

Comment: I shared more code. please look at my other post. thank you!

Comment: Don't repost. If your different posts are the same question, then delete one of them. If they are different, then you need to post code in both locations.

Comment: just did. please take a look at the code at your convenience. thank you. !

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code is the selection that is used to create the chart

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, v), Cells(3, v + 1)).Select
ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

Now we need to find the `ActiveSheet`. Backing up a few lines we find this:

```
Sheets(j).Select
```

What is Sheet "j"? j gets defined by this line near the top of your posted code:

```
j = j + 1
```

What this tells me (as best I can guess based on what you have posted here) is that the code is looping through the sheets and creating charts and doing other formatting.

As for where in the sheet the code is pulling data, that is coming from your variable `v`. I have to make some guesses (1. because I can't see your sheet structure, and 2. because there is too much code to look through here). v is set to 53, and then added to in various loops in the code.

That is the best I'm willing to do given how broad your question is. This isn't the best forum for general "what does this mean" questions.

I'll also repeat the bit in my comment about looking at the chart source data (in the Excel window) as that may help decipher what is going on.

Comment: ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:G14")
    ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1"
in the above context, i know the chart sourced range a3-g14 from sheet1, identified by keyword "source". but i the code i posted, i did not see any keyword. any further explaination please???

Comment: From my above comment to your question: "Excel is likely using the active cell to create the chart." Stepping through the code execution you'll likely see that the active cell is somewhere in the range `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:G14")`.